# starting postgresql and pgadmin in windows without installation

Tags: postgresql

How can I start PostgreSQL and pgAdmin III in windows without installation. I do not have admin rights in a system. so I need to start the application without installing . How can I do that?

Comment: may be this can help you https://www.tutlinks.com/install-postgresql-without-admin-rights-windows/

Answer (score 86, accepted):

1. Download the ZIP file from https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries
2. Unzip the archive into a directory of your choice (the archive is created such that unzipping it, it will create a directory `pgsql` with everything else below that)
3. Run `initdb` (this can be found in the subdirectory `pgsql\bin`)

   ```
    initdb -D c:\Users\Arthur\pgdata -U postgres -W -E UTF8 -A scram-sha-256
   ```

   This will create the postgres "data directory" (aka the "cluster") in `c:\Users\Arthur\pgdata`. You need to make sure that the user running this command has full read/write privileges on that directory.

   `-U postgres` creates the superuser as `postgres`, `-W` will prompt you for the password of the superuser, `-E UTF8` will create the database with `UTF-8` encoding and `-A scram-sha-256` enables the password authentication.
4. To start Postgres, run:

   ```
    pg_ctl -D c:\Users\Arthur\pgdata -l logfile start
   ```

   this **has**(!) to be done as the user who ran `initdb` to avoid any problems with the access to the data directory.
5. To shutdown Postgres, run:

   ```
    pg_ctl -D c:\Users\Arthur\pgdata stop
   ```
6. `psql.exe` (the command line client) is located in the `bin` directory. Starting with Postgres 9.6 the pgAdmin executable `pgAdmin4.exe` is located in the sub-directory `"pgAdmin 4\bin"`.
7. Optionally create a Windows service to automatically run Postgres (**must** be run using a Windows administrator account)

   ```
    pg_ctl register -N postgresql -D c:\Users\Arthur\pgdata
   ```

Comment: I tried the following steps but I am getting an error:$ ./postgres/bin/psql 
psql: FATAL:  role "user" does not exist

Comment: For those who are using `postgresql-10.4-1-windows`, pgAdmin4 will failed to connect to application server. `postgresql-9.6.9-1-windows` does not have this problem.

Comment: @SolomonUcko: four years ago there was no better way

Comment: Is there any way to see what other ones are available?

Comment: @SolomonUcko: see the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/client-authentication.html

Comment: creating directory c:/Users/Arthur/pgdata ... initdb: error: could not create directory "c:/Users/Arthur": Permission denied

Comment: Thanks a lot for this post, spent hours to install postgressql in windows trying each and every solution, finally able to do it with above steps and connect. So much frustrating.

Comment: How can I set the path for pg_config for this case?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  can you please check this, I have followed the steps and have tried all the solutions , but no luck. Then created this ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67046283/postgresql-initdb-initialize-a-new-database-cluster-has-stopped-working

Comment: Is there an up-to-date link for the download?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you. This worked for me. But, i was getting error while starting psql.exe

The error was "psql: FATAL : role [user] does not exist."

To resolve this, i followed the below steps:

1. Be on the same folder path (where you have initdb.exe) i.e. source-folder/pgsql/bin
2. Run "psql -U postgres". This will ask for password.
3. Now enter the password that was set during postgres intialization. This will open the psql command prompt.

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried above method its working fine, but when i tried to connect it via JDBC i used to get

> *"The authentication type 10 is not supported. Check that you have configured the pg_hba.conf file to include the client's IP address or
>   subnet, and that it is using an authentication scheme supported by the
>   driver."*

This happens because **scram-sha-256** has some issue([refer here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/DM2PR0601MB0956C30DE367876D88672234E4E40%40DM2PR0601MB0956.namprd06.prod.outlook.com)), i couldn't understand in depth, so i **changed it to md5**, All started to work smoothly.hope it helps

**.\initdb -D D:\database\dbdata -U postgres -W -E UTF8 -A md5**