# PyQt5: Driver not loaded

Tags: python, postgresql, pyqt5

So, its like these, I made a cluster database for **PostgreSQL**, with the help of this answer [starting postgresql and pgadmin in windows without installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441873/starting-postgresql-and-pgadmin-in-windows-without-installation][1]).
So the Database is working I can see on **PgAdmin**, but when I tried to connect it through **PyQt5** I got these error:

> Driver not loaded Driver not loaded

I tried **QPSQL** driver and **QPSQL7** driver but still the same error so I went to see all available drivers i got:

> QSQLITE, QMYSQL, QMYSQL3, QODBC, QODBC3, QPSQL, QPSQL7

when I tried to read the driver error I got:

> Driver not loaded

and when I tried to read the database error I got:

> Driver not loaded

But when I try to Use **psycopg2** lib it works, perfectly.
So that got me thinking maybe I installed my **PyQt5** wrongly, but I used **pip** to install all libs.
Does anyone know why is it happening and can anyone help me?

```
def creatConn():
    _db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QPSQL')
    _db.setDatabaseName('database')
    _db.setUserName('username')
    _db.setPassword('password')
    _db.setPort(int('port')
    _db.setHostName('host')
    if _db.open():
       return _db    
    else:
       return False
```

Comment: Can you post your code? Otherwise it will be impossible to help.

Comment: Done, but I was doing some test in my other OS and on MacOS it works and on linux but on windows doesn't work.

Comment: now im about to reinstall the whole python, see if its going to work. maybe there was something bad on my installation.

Comment: can you please tell me the output of following code in the same program? it tells which drivers are correctly installed,
`dbliste = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.drivers()
print(dbliste)`

Comment: i get this: QSQLITE, QMYSQL, QMYSQL3, QODBC, QODBC3, QPSQL, QPSQL7

Answer (score -2, accepted):

im done reinstalling python and as how I was predicting, it works. 
I don't know what was wrong because I reinstalled, PyQt5 the same way I installed the first time. `pip install PyQt5`.
Thank you for all the help.