# PostgreSQL 12.3 Windows x86-64 Installer doesn't start

Tags: postgresql, installation, windows-10, pgadmin

I am trying to install PostgreSQL 12.3 version using installer from [here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads), my system runs on Windows 10 (64bit). I did this procedure on different laptops (running on win10 64bit) and didn't encounter any problems until now. When I download installer and double-click on it, I am asked for administrator permissions (I grant permission to install software). After that, EDB Postgres logo appears on the screen for a few seconds and disappears and this is it. Nothing else is happening. In normal way after logo disappear, Postgres Installer should launch asking where to install, what port to use and other similar questions, but in my case it doesn't happen. I now that I can use Zip archive to install Postgresql manually, (I found how to do it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441873/starting-postgresql-and-pgadmin-in-windows-without-installation)), but this answer skips most important part - configuration.
Also I tried older versions of installers and every time I ended up with same result - loads only EDB Postgres logo...

Comment: "*but this answer skips most important part - configuration*" - the installer won't do any other "configuration" then the manual installation using the ZIP archive will do (except for registering a Windows service)

Comment: Please, read more carefully before commenting. I found instruction how to install Postgresql using zip archive, but that answer skipped most important step - configuration. I will explain in more detail - I found how to launch postgresql using zip arcdhyve, but in that tutorial there is no word about how to configure and connect  to db using PgAdmin.

Comment: Well, your questions doesn't mention you meant the configuration of  pgAdmin (rather than Postgres) - which is something the installer won't do either. But in the end there is not much to "configure". You start pgAdmin, enter the connection details and your done

Comment: My question is why Postgresql installer doesn't launch on windows 10. I am not asking if installer configures something or not.