# PostgreSQL initdb initialize a new database cluster has stopped working

Tags: windows, postgresql, installation, postgresql-initdb

During install of PostgreSQL using binary zip file , this error occurs , when i try to run this command

```
initdb.exe -U postgres -A password -E utf8 -W -D C:\pgsql\data.
```

Error Message:

> "initdb initialize a new database cluster has stopped working"

it works on some machines and fails on others, I am using latest version 13.2 binaries.

```
Windows Event log:
Faulting application name: initdb.exe, version: 13.0.1.20314, time stamp: 0x5faa5f0f
Faulting module name: ucrtbase.dll, version: 10.0.14393.3659, time stamp: 0x5e9140a1
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x000000000006c9e8
Faulting process id: 0x579c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d72d5bc0a912a0
Faulting application path: C:\pgsql\bin\initdb.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
Report Id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

[pls see more details here](https://www.postgresql-archive.org/BUG-16957-initdb-exe-initialize-a-database-cluster-has-stopped-working-td6193412.html)

Comment: There must be more error messages than just that line.

Comment: when I ran this command , "initdb.exe -U postgres -A password -E utf8 -W -D C:\pgsql\data." , it gave me only above error , and the given windows event log error message. After failing to install binary files I dowloaded the official postgresql database installer , which also failed but that gave me a log file , which I am updating in this question , but I need solution for binary installation , not for postgresql gui installer. @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Did you try to turn of your virus scanner?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes I have tried permission issues ,virus scanning , firewall , directory change ,user creation and deletion but no luck. I even tried installing the official postgresql installer , but still error occurs in initdb.exe